# Ionic 2 Deeplink: App does not navigate to desired page

Tags: ionic2, deep-linking

I am using Ionic 2 Deeplink plugin and testing this on real iOS device. I managed to get the app runs, when clicking the link but the app does not navigate to the desired page, which is in this case, it should be itemPage but app the went straight to homePage. Below is my code:

```
  Deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
    '/items/:itemId/': this.itemPage
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    console.log('Deeplink: ' + JSON.stringify(match.$link))
    // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
    // match.$args - the args passed in the link
    // match.$link - the full link data
    console.log('Successfully matched route: ', JSON.stringify(match));
  }, (nomatch) => {
    // nomatch.$link - the full link data
    console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
  });
```

Should I add a `this.nav.push(this.itemPage, itemId)` during the subscription to make the navigation works or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

What's your setting in config.xml? you should use link like: `your_url_schema://your_deeplink_host/theAppPath`